# Tailwind styles multi select of mat-select but should'nt affect the component

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I am having one angular material mat-select component with the [multiple] attribute and one without. For some reason the one with [multiple] gets some odd styling (the border which you can see, and it's also too big) by tailwind and I don't get why.

Here is one screenshot showing the problem and one showing the styles which get applied.
I don't know where to start because I don't understand why tailwind adds this "public" styles.
[image: Both components]
[image: The components with the styles]

This is the code which produces the two components:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let role of roleFormGroups; index as i">
        <div [formGroupName]="i" class="flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>{{'abc_name' | translate }}</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="role_id" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of availableRoles" [value]="option.id">
                        {{option.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>{{'some_label' | translate }}</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="site_ids" required multiple >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of availableScopes" [value]="option.id">
                        {{option.option}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" class="self-start !mt-3" (click)="removeRole(i)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

I am using tailwindcss 3.0.13 and angular 12.2.13 and tailwindcss/forms 0.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The tailwindcss/forms plugin was producing the problem. After removing, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 15 you can add style on your css file

```
.mat-mdc-select-multiple{
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
```

For Angular 14 and below you can add style on your css file

```
.mat-select-multiple{
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks- had this issue and your css code got rid of the unwanted border for multiple-select lists right away.